# Pure CSS: Show image2 above/over/on top image1 on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

[**SOLVED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3m393/):

I can't figure out how to display an image(two) above/over my current visible image(one) when hovered.

Html:

```
<img class="two" src="img/2.png" alt="bulb">
<img class="one" src="img/1.png" alt="me">
```

CSS:

```
.one {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 50px;
}

.two {
opacity: 0;
}

.one:hover .two {
opacity: 1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `.one:hover+.two` instead of `.one:hover .two`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If you want to show another image below the first image, than you need to change your DOM, as CSS cannot select the previous element, but it can select adjacent image, what you are using is `.one:hover .two` which will select an element having class `.two` nested under element having class `.one` on `hover` but since the elements are adjacent, you can use the selector below, but note that you need to change the element order in the DOM.

```
.one:hover + .two {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5h4aZ/2/)

---

I assume *Above* means on hover you want to swap the image, so if that's what you want than use CSS Positioning techniques by setting your images to `position: absolute;` which are nested under `position: relative;` container.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5h4aZ/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div img { /* Setting images to absolute */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

div img:nth-of-type(2) { /* Initially hiding image 2 */
    opacity: 0;
}

div:hover img:nth-of-type(1) { /* On hover of div we hide 1st image */
    opacity: 0;
}

div:hover img:nth-of-type(2) { /* On hover of div we show 2nd image */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

You can also add `transition` property to smoothly swap the image on `hover`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5h4aZ/1/)

```
div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
This is what I meant with above:
http://jsfiddle.net/3m393/

I used your 'below image' method and styled it to be on top. I hope it is the smartest way :)

Comment: @user3109752 Yea, we can make a good use of positioning there :) and you welcome..

Comment: @user3109752 By the way, it would be better if you wrap the images inside `position: relative;` parent and than `position` the second image using `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `position:absolute` and wrap your images with a `div`

```
div.images{
  border:solid green 4px;
  height:120px;
  width:120px;;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position:relative;
}
.images img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0
}
.two {    
  opacity:0;
  z-index:1;
}

.images:hover .two {
  opacity: 10;    
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IqIpEQA/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

if it does not matter which one of your images come first you can change your html like this :

```
<img class="one" src="img/1.png" alt="me">
<img class="two" src="img/2.png" alt="bulb">
```

and use this CSS:

```
img.one:hover + img.two {
opacity: 1;
}
```

because there is no backward in CSS.